# After updating from typo3 7 to typo3 8 several invalid values in page contents

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I updated a typo3 site from version 6 to version 7 and now to version 8 heading for 9 or 10. Now some contents on my page are missing. When I look in the page editor all elements have errors like [INVALID VALUE ('ce_head-image')] or [INVALID VALUE ('ce_product')]. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content elements (CEs) have no rendering definition.
the rendering definition can be missing because of:

- the basic rendering extension is missing

  - `EXT:CSC` leaves the core and is an TER extension
  - the names of the CEs is changed inside the basic rendering extension (there should be an upgrade wizard)
- the same for CE types defined by additional extensions

  - extension is no longer supported for the newer TYPO3 version
  - changed names in newer versions (upgrade wizard?)
  - the registering of additional CEs does not work any longer as it has been changed in the core

As the names you have sounds unfamiliar my firsst guess would be the last reason.

Comment: I can't find any extension with the key CSC ?

Comment: CSC = css_styled_content replaced by FSC = fluid_styled_contend. but also the definition of CEs has changed much since CSC was commonly used

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Is there a approach how I can determine what causes this? And if your last reason would apply (which sounds most plausible to me too), can I reuse the old content elements in any way to restore the old contet? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: for the default CEs of CSC there was a wizard to convert the data if necessary. but additional CEs could not be converted automatically. For these CEs (`ce_head-image` and `ce_product`) you need to modify their rendering and probably their registration. to be compatible to the current CEs you might convert some data as some fields have changed (for images the fieldname has changed from `image` over `asset` to `media`)

Comment: Thank you for the instruction, thats something I can work with :)